# HTML5 Shiv Conflict in IE 7 & 8

Tags: html, css, html5shiv

**What I'm trying to do**
I am trying to use HTML5 shiv to alow for HTML5 elements to work in IE.  I have used this in two other instances with no problem.

**What I'm doing**
I have included this script in my header immediately after opening my header tag before all other scripts are loaded.

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I have also included in my CSS the standard display: block style to these HTML5 elements.

**What is Happening**
This however is not working in IE 7 & 8.  The elements are not rendered.  From what I have read HTML5 Shiv can be pretty strict on its tags.  So for example, my  tag loads as such:

```
<html lang="en" jQuery19109983433033032547="1">
```

My body tag also loads as this:

```
<body class="sitedefault">
```

I have kept my version of JQuery loading consistent, have followed other directions I have read pertaiing to HTML5 Shiv as I have in my prior implementations of this but am still hitting this snag.  Any help at this point would be incredibly appreciated!

I have also tried hosting the Shiv file locally with no luck.

Here is how the source looks in IE8:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<!-- Pano-Framework Requirements Start //-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="/script/respond.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/pano-framework.css" />
<!-- Pano-Framework Requirements End //-->
```

There is plenty of stuff loading after this but that's the first section of my .  I am at a complete loss as to why this isn't working.

**Update**
I have found that IE is loading this stylesheet at the very top of my  section which could explain this issue:

```
article {
    DISPLAY: block
}
aside {
    DISPLAY: block
}
dialog {
    DISPLAY: block
}
figcaption {
    DISPLAY: block
}.....
```

It loads like this:

```
<style>CSS Stylesheet</style>
```

I am not sure what is loading this or why it is loading in this spot above the HTML5shiv?  Any ideas?

Comment: What elements of HTML5 are not displaying properly?

Comment: If something is being added to your site dynamically, it is probably one of your scripts. Disable them temporarily to see if the shiv is working. `Display: block` is actually what the shiv should be doing.

Comment: The standard elements, nav, article, header, footer.  I am not sure where that CSS is being loaded from though.  I haven't seen it on other HTML5shiv implementations I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this to work but I'm not entirely sure what I changed to trigger the fix.  My final code, however it this:

```
<!-- Pano-Framework Requirements Start //-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://staging.new.informationweek.com/styles/pano-framework.css">
<script src="/script/respond.min.js"></script>
<!-- Pano-Framework Requirements End //-->
```

The biggest difference I see is my  tag pulling in my stylesheet.

I appreciate the help everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Also make sure your IE browser mode is not set to `Quirks`. Hit F12 or go to settings>F12 developer options.

Set `Document Mode: Standards`

**EDIT**

Simple HTML5 page with shiv

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
body{margin:0 auto;}menu{background-color:gray;text-align:center;margin:0;}header{background-color:silver;text-align:center;margin:0;}article{text-align:center;background-color:#A9A9A9;margin:0;}footer{text-align:center;background-color:silver;margin:0;}section{background-color:#ADD8E6;text-align:center;margin:auto;}    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <menu>&lt;menu&gt;</menu>
    <header>&lt;header&gt;</header>
    <article>&lt;article&gt;</article>
    <section>&lt;section&gt;</section>
    <footer>&lt;footer&gt;</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Also make sure to `Allow Blocked Content` in IE if the message pops up. That is the shiv script.

Comment: I tried your update with no luck.  My document mode does default to Standards as well.

Comment: @Yuschick if you are using IE greater than 9, set browser mode as desired, example `IE8` and document mode to `IE8 Standards`

Comment: I haven't seen `jQuery19109983433033032547="1"` as a valid tag. That could be the issue. Otherwise, the provided code would display HTML5 tags properly in IE less than 9.

Comment: I am unsure where that JQuery tag is being loaded to even remove it.

Comment: @Yuschick take a look at the update for a simple HTML5 shiv example. I have tested it and its guaranteed to work in IE 7 and 8. Make sure blocked content allowed.

Answer (score 0):

From the [HTML5 Shiv Readme](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/readme.md):

> Include the HTML5 shiv in the  of your page in a conditional comment and ***after*** any stylesheets.

Comment: This has been tested. Placing it after does not make a difference.